# How to I create my database to use with sequelize-typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to create a project in node.js where I have a mysql database. So I installed sequelize-typescript etc because my code is done in typescript. I currently have this code:

```
const sequelize =  new Sequelize({
        database: 'myDB',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        username: 'root',
        password: '1234',
        storage: ':memory:',
        modelPaths: [__dirname + '/src/models']
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

But how do I create the actual database I want to connect to and set the password and everything? It currently gives me the "unable to connect" error.

Comment: I personally suggest you that use sequelize migrations. It will really help you.

Comment: @narayansharma91 I installed something called sequelize-CLI for that purpose but I have to say I have a lot of trouble understanding the documentation on the Sequelize website. Could you walk me through step by step how I create a database with this method?

Comment: Hey, @coding_pianist sequelize won't create a database for you. This is something you have to create manually. You can manage database schema through migrations and working with database operations using ORM eg. Create, Get, Update etc. through sequelize.

Comment: How do I create the database manually?

Comment: @coding_pianist Probably you know how to do this by now, but adding this comment for others reaching this question, in case they don't know how to create a DB. This tutorial could be helpful: https://docs.rapidminer.com/7.6/server/installation/creating_mysql_db.html#:~:text=Using%20a%20GUI,-Use%20these%20instructions&text=Open%20the%20MySQL%20Workbench%20as,command%20that%20creates%20the%20schema.